# Tips for shortening this type-safe addition in JavaScript

Tags: code-golf, tips, javascript

Consider:

```
c=(a,b)=>(+a||0)+(+b||0)
```

Yes, it is not good to solve it like that. But I want to shorten it even more. If `a` is a string and `b` is a string, then return `0`. If one is a number, return it (floats and intergers). And if both inputs are numbers, then return the sum (if either string can be cast to a number, treat it as a number).

I tried to shorten this more, but I just can’t.

This is the specification for the task:

### Usage

```
node app.js
```

### Expected behavior

The program returns the sum of two numbers. If no numbers are provided, the result should be `0`. If only one number is provided, only that number should be returned.

### Tests

```
node app.js 4 5 # 9

node app.js 4 # 4

node app.js 4 a # 4

node app.js a 4 # 4

node app.js a b # 0

node app.js 2.1 b # 2.1

node app.js 2.1 2.5 # 4.6

node app.js # 0
```

### Update

It also needs to handle floats as well not only integers.

This is my current code (only the code on line 1 should be optimized to be as small as possible):

```
c=(a,b)=>(+a||0)+(+b||0)

const input1 = process.argv[2];
const input2 = process.argv[3];

const result = c(input1, input2);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What if `a` and `b` are both strings, but ones which cast into numbers? Your code treats them as numbers, but the description seems to imply we need to actually check if they're strings

Comment: no actually strings that can be casted into a float should be treated as a float

Comment: Just curious: why do you want to shorten it further? I know which website we're currently on. I just hope not too much golfing code is used in production.

Comment: This code is not used in production. It is just a bet with my Prof. He said you can't shorten this code any more.

Comment: I don't have an answer for the actual implementation, but you can win your bet with your Professor by just changing `(a,b)=>` to `a=>b=>` for -1 byte. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen maybe thats ok for him. Thanks a lot. Although I would love to shorten it even more before telling him

Comment: The combination of floats and `NaN` makes this difficult. I'd love to be proven wrong, but I doubt it can be shorter than the 23 bytes you have right now.. [`f=a=>b=>a- -b||~-a-~b`](https://tinyurl.com/5k8eswk8) is the closest I got, but it fails for float+string combination (e.g. `4.1,'a'`).

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript, <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```javascript
c=a=>b=>~-a-~b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P9k20dYuydauTjdRty7pf0FRZl6JRrKGoSYQaf4HAA)

Comment: Crazy, but i actually need a code that also works with floats

Answer (score 8):

If you only need to handle integers, you can use bitwise operations to convert them into a numbers:

```javascript
c=(a,b)=>(a|0)+(b|b) // Both ways shown fine
```

Or even shorter:

```javascript
c=a=>b=>~-a-~b // (a-1)-(-b-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P9k20dYuydauTjdRty7pf0FRZl6JRrKGoSYQaXLBuOqJ6qgCQHn1JHWgwH8A)

This doesn't work for floats, but this trick seems unmentioned elsewhere, so I've left it here.

Comment: I actually need to handle floats as well. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: It also doesn't work with integers outside the signed 32-bit range

Comment: Nice to know. I am interested if there will be an even shorter answer which can handle floats

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 23 bytes

```
c=(a,b)=>(a||0)-(-b||0)
```

Comment: Hi there, I testet it and it works. But not fully, if the first input (a) is a string. Then I get the return value NaN, but it should return the value of the second number. Read all the test values I pasted in my description.

Comment: Ah you're right, overlooked that it would have to work for non-numeric strings as well (besides empty string)